# Regular Expression to match a mandatory symbol in an optional part of a string?

Tags: python, regex

What is the regular expression that matches for a mandatory symbol in an optional part of a string.

For example, `abcd` will be matched by the RE but, if I add `:`, the resulting string will not be matched unless I add letter(s) afterwards like this `abcd:efg`.

So, the optional part is the `:` onward, and the mandatory symbol in this optional part is the `:` itself.

`abcd:efg:hijk` need also to be matched.

**UPDATE**:
I tried this `^([a-z]|_)*(:[a-z]|_)*$` but it did not work as expected.

Comment: Is there a question in your question?

Comment: Have you tried something and met some problem?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I updated the question with my attempt.

Comment: Why downvotes? This is good question...

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with your regex. It matches word characters, and then optionally a colon and more word characters. Isn't that exactly what you want? Please add some examples for strings that should and should not match. Edit: Just realized the regex doesn't match `abcd:efg:hijk`. But some examples would still do this question a lot of good.

Comment: @Rawing For some reason, my regex does not match `abc:def`!

Comment: If you don't want to be downvoted, you have to give examples and _clearly_ state which ones of them should be matched and which ones should not, and _why_. And if someone asks you a question or asks for more/better examples, you'd do well to answer that question and add some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include more examples and counter-examples, but this should be close enough to your goal:

```
^[a-z_]+(:[a-z_]+)*$
```

Here's a [test](https://regex101.com/r/HytKFK/1).

The problem with your `^([a-z]|_)*(:[a-z]|_)*$` regex is that it only matches one letter after each `:`. [`a:b:c:d` matches but not `a:b:c:de`](https://regex101.com/r/0PZySX/1).

Finally, please note that `(:[a-z]|_)` is :

- a colon followed by a letter
- or an underscore.

It doesn't match a colon followed by an underscore!

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if you can also help me understand why I got the downvotes to later avoid whatever mistakes I may have committed :)

Comment: @PatternRecognition: You should probably state exactly which regex pattern you tried, with which regexengine. You should write which strings it matches, which strings it doesn't match, which strings it should match and which strings it shouldn't match.

Comment: @EricDuminil but wouldn't this match "abcd" in string "abcd:"? From his question I understood he doesn't want that?

Comment: @AleksandarMakragić: No, it doesn't match `abcd:`. See the linked test in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a regex with a positive lookbehind. This also makes it easier to group the matching parts. It first matches the first string, and then matches all the following strings when preceded with a ":"

```
([a-z_]*)((?<=:):[a-z_])?
```

https://regex101.com/r/NkiZ3g/1

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you need to know how to express optionality for a stretch longer than a single character. Try this:

```
^abcd(:efg)?$
```

For `abcd` and `efg` substitute whatever you're really looking for.

Comment: Have you tested that regex before you posted it? This is clearly wrong because this will match case abcd:

Comment: Thanks but this cannot match a string with three parts (e.g. `abcd:efg:hijk`), can it?

Comment: @PatternRecognition `efg` is intended as a symbol in the spirit of your question. That is why I said &quot;for `efg` substitute whatever you are looking for&quot;. You didn&#39;t actually say what that was. You could substitute `.+` for `efg` if you want to match a string of any characters including a colon.